# Check if at least one cell is selected in each section of a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I want to create a simple method that will determine whether or not at least one cell in each section is selected.

Something like this:

```
func checkSections () ->Bool {

    let array : [IndexPath] = self.selectedIndexPaths.copy() as! [IndexPath];
    for indexPath: IndexPath in array {
        let SectionString : String? = self.sectionHeaderTitleArray[indexPath.section] // this will return the names of the selected sections but no way to use that

        // check all the sections and see if they contain a selected cell
    }



}
```

I know it's incomplete, but I have no idea how to start creating it and I'm hoping to find help to start the func at least. Please understand that I haven't touched anything programming related in 5+ years and I was never a professional

Comment: You should not check the data against UI stuff. So first you need to store the selection state somewhere out of the UI itself.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini He is not checking anything against the UI, as far as I can tell. To get the selection states just use `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`, so there is no need to store the selection state elsewhere

Comment: They could be get reused @NoodleOfDeath.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini table view cells should be reused; `UITableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` is entirely data derived and completely separate from `UITableViewCell.isSelected`, which may not be in as a predictable state due to reuse and should not be used to check data state but instead for animation and appearance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected indexPaths as follows:

`let array: [IndexPath] = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`

And then something like:

```
for indexPath: IndexPath in array {
   if let section = indexPath.section {
   // yes, we have a selected cell in this section
   }
}
```

Comment: this works but only for the currently selected cell, I have multiple selections and if I have section 1 with a selected cell and I send that code to check section 2 and 1, it'll give me that the section I'm not touching right now isn't selected

Comment: @Jp4Real you need to set `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` to allow multiple selections in multiple sections of your table view.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```swift
/// Checks if the number of selected sections equals 
/// the number of sections in the table view
func checkSections() -> Bool {
    let selectedSections = 
      Set(tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.map { $0.section } ?? [])
    return selectedSections.count == tableView.numberOfSections
}
```

You also need to set `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` to allow multiple selections in multiple sections of your table view.